# SDL Pointers and References

Tags: c++, c, pointers, sdl, pass-by-reference

I've never really understood pointers/references but in the code I've written I get a error saying

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
int SDL_UpperBlit(SDL_Surface *, SDL_Rect *, SDL_Surface *, SDL_Rect *)
'
```

I really should understand pointers first but could anyone help me?

```
void MapManager::draw(SDL_Surface *surface, SDL_Surface &mainSurface, int x, int y){
SDL_BlitSurface(surface, NULL, mainSurface, new SDL_Rect{x, y, 32, 32});
}
```

used as

```
draw(img_brickImage, *inDisplay, x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE);
```

display:

```
SDL_Surface* display;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the signature of SDL_BlitSurface:

```
int SDL_BlitSurface(SDL_Surface*    src,
                    const SDL_Rect* srcrect,
                    SDL_Surface*    dst,
                    SDL_Rect*       dstrect)
```

Note how both `src` and `dst` are `SDL_Surface` pointers (`SDL_Surface*`).

You are passing to `dst` a reference, `SDL_Surface &mainSurface`, which is not a pointer.

You can either change the function signature to receive a pointer instead (and also change where you are calling it):

```
void MapManager::draw(SDL_Surface *surface, SDL_Surface *mainSurface, int x, int y)
```

Or to pass the address of the reference to the expected pointer parameter:

```
SDL_BlitSurface(surface, NULL, &mainSurface, new SDL_Rect{x, y, 32, 32});
```

---

> I really should understand pointers first (...)

Yes, I second that. Understanding pointers is fundamental to C/C++ programming, and SDL is no exception, as you see SDL constantly uses pointers.